# How Do I Limit A Standard FIFO Queue ThroughPut In The AWS CDK?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk, throughput

I have created a FIFO queue, but would like to limit the number of requests it can make, so as not to overload the server it is sending those requests to.

**CDK Code:**

```
this.intoMagento = new Queue(this, "intoAPI", {
  queueName: `intoAPI.fifo`,
  fifo: true,
  contentBasedDeduplication: true,
  visibilityTimeout: Duration.minutes(5),
  fifoThroughputLimit: FifoThroughputLimit.PER_QUEUE,
});
```

Whilst I've limited the throughput `PER_QUEUE`, how do I tell it I only want to do 600 `HTTP` `POST` requests per minute? Do I do it in my Lambda Queue Consumer?

Also, is `FifoThroughputLimit.PER_QUEUE` only appropriate for high throughout SQS queues, or can it apply to standard queues too? I have many message groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQS Queue throughput is not a fine-grained, user-determined setting<sup>*</sup>.  Rather, it's a consequence of a mix of factors, including Queue type quotas, consumer count, batching, and message partition patterns.

The Lambda [Event Source Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) integration with SQS pulls messages as fast as possible.  However, here are a couple ways to limit your Lambda consumers' message consumption:

1. The quick-and-dirty approach is to [cap the number of concurrent Lambda consumers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/) with the Event Source Mapping's [MaximumConcurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-max-concurrency) setting.  If you're lucky, a MaximumConcurrency set to the lower limit of 2 (and [batchSize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_event_sources.SqsEventSourceProps.html#batchsize) set to 1) will slow processing to a rate that is acceptably close to your desired limit.  I guess you could also periodically enable/disable the integration on a schedule if you need an additional lever.
2. If you want finer-grained throughput control, you'll need to give up the conveniences of the Event Source Mapping integration.  Trigger the Lambda on a schedule with EventBridge.  You'll have more precise control over messages/hour, but will need to pull and delete messages from the queue manually.  If you have a hard 600/hr limit, you'll additionally need  to track of the hour-to-date processed message count (say, in a DynamoDB table) and exit early from the Lambda if the limit has been reached for a given period.

---

* Whilst the name might suggest otherwise, the CDK Queue construct's [fifoThroughputLimit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_sqs.Queue.html#fifothroughputlimit) is not a speed limit setting.  Rather, it is [part of the setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-sqs-queue.html#cfn-sqs-queue-fifothroughputlimit) to enable [High-throughput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/high-throughput-fifo.html) on FIFO Queues.